# Data Bind InvHeader/InvItems using Maui XAML in nested StackLayout where InvHeader.CustId = InvItem.CustId?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, maui, code-behind

I'm trying to create a master/detail page in Maui. Just like an invoice with invoice items, this page must display sever 'invoices' each with their own invoice items.

Let's say we have a list of invoices. Each invoice has two associated tables in SQL Server (the Header and the items).

I pull each of those tables into an array of classes - one array for invoice headers, one for invoice items.

I need to display a scrolling list of All invoices. So the page would display Invoice Header #1 and the items associated with that invId,

Then display Invoice header #2 - and the invoice items associated with That invoice.

The invoice items must be specific to the invoice being displayed - and currently I'm failing badly at this?

It .. Almost .. works as I can display All the InvItems in the nested grid under each InvHeader, but I can't limit them to Only display the InvItems where InvHeader.CustId = InvItem.CustId.

If I can just get the parameter sent to the InvItemsForCustIdConverter, then I'm done.

It just needs the InvHeader.CustId for the StackLayout in which the InvItems StackLayout is nested.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage x:Name="parentView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MauiClient"
             x:Class="MauiClient.Invoice"
             Title="Invoice">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:InvItemsForCustIdConverter x:Key="InvItemsForCustIdConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <!-- Header section -->
            <Label Text="Hospitals" FontSize="Title" />
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding invHeaders}" BackgroundColor="Blue">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Company}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Addr1}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Phone}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding CustId}" BackgroundColor="Red"  TextColor="White" />
                            <!-- Invoice items section -->
                            <Label Text="Tech Times" FontSize="Title" BackgroundColor="Yellow" TextColor="Black"/>
                            <StackLayout BindingContext="{Binding BindingContext, Source={x:Reference parentView}}" BackgroundColor="Green">
                                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding InvItems, Converter={StaticResource InvItemsForCustIdConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding CustId}}">
                                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="20">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding ItemId}" />
                                                <Label Text="{Binding CustId}" BackgroundColor="Red"  TextColor="White" />
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

```
public class InvoiceViewModel  {
        public List<InvHeader> InvHeaders { get; set; }
        public List<InvItem> InvItems { get; set; }
}
```

```
// changing ConverterParameter={Binding CustId}}">  to ConverterParameter={Binding InvHeader.CustId}}">
// just changes the PATH in parameter to PATH InvHeader.CustId
// we are always passing null??
// value shows as 39 InvItems
// trying a few variations, all of them return null in parameter
// <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding InvItems, Converter={StaticResource InvItemsForCustIdConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding InvHeader.CustId}}">
// <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding InvItems, Converter={StaticResource InvItemsForCustIdConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding CustId}}">
// <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding InvItems, Converter={StaticResource InvItemsForCustIdConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding CustId, Source={x:Reference parentView}, Path=InvHeader}}">

public class InvItemsForCustIdConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
      return value; // If I return the invItems then the display works, but does not Limit the InvItems to those matching the InvHeader StackLayout

      if (value is List<InvItem> invItems && parameter is string custId)
      {
          return invItems.Where(x => x.CustId == custId).ToList();
      }
      return null;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish, can you elaborate on your goal? You're also leaving out important bits of the code, such as the XAML markup where you have defined the Grids.

Comment: I updated the query with XAML and some clarification as to what I'm trying to accomplish.  Thanks!!

Comment: I haven't read your code or question in detail, but sometimes complicated layouts are easier to do with c# code. c# code is more flexible in adding children based on logical conditions. Search `maui xamarin c# markup`. (I added xamarin, because there are some older docs / examples that work the same way in Maui.) In your case, it won't be one giant markup for the whole page. Instead, describe one element in markup, then add the children one at a time. Something like `myelement.Children.Add(new ...);`

Comment: I think you're right about using code-behind!

I reworked the XAML completely (changed all the code above) and have it working .. except .. that my code-behind converter is Not getting passed the CustID from the enclosing InvHeader StackLaout but rather a null for everything I've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I approached the question in a different fashion with modified code in another StackOverlow thread and recieved an Excellent suggestion along with almost working code from Jessie Zhang -MSFT.

I didn't use his TempInvItems list but rather only a single InvItems list that was filtered for each InvHeader List item as follows:

```
foreach (var wsc in InvHeaders)
{
    wsc.InvItems = InvItems.Where(x => x.CustId == wsc.CustId).ToList();
}
```

And the code works perfectly!

The link to that solution by Jessie Zhang -MSFT is here:
[filtering InvItems before displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76040700/how-to-intelligently-create-and-debug-complex-maui-data-bindings-for-nested-stac)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to display a scrolling list of All invoices. So the page would
> display Invoice Header #1 and the items associated with that invId.

I recommended that you could use the SQL to query the data you want from the two tables instead of using the `ConverterParameter` to write the logic code in the code-behind.

If you want to handle the data in the code-behind, you can get the data of the two tables into two lists with each own entities then you can address the data more convenient.

Comment: I already had two separate lists of the InvHeaders and InvItems.  The problem was in limiting the nested StackLayou to Only display items for the associated InvItems and I'd hoped a Converted would resolve that (which it would have if I could have passed a value from the parent View as a parameter to the converter.

I posted a modified version of my question and Jessie Zhang -MSFT came up with a completely different idea I hadn't thought of.    I'll post a link to that in case anyone has the same problem - but I would Really like to resolve my converter parameter issue!!