# How to intelligently create and debug complex Maui Data Bindings for nested Stack Layouts?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, maui, code-behind

I've been trying to create a Data Binding that would access a value from a parent Stack Layout.

I created a converter figuring that this would give me some visibility as to what my binding was doing.

However, I'm just getting a null for the parameter value - that I need to be set to the text value of a field in the parent Stack Layout?

There .. Must .. be some techniques to intelligently debug Bindings and get some visibility into how to create the correct binding?

I'v tried creating a lable to give me some clue as to what the binding is doing - trying many variations of the following Label but .. I've had little success?

```
<Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference parentView}, StringFormat='{0}'}" />
```

Here's my converter where the parameter is always mull.

```
// changing ConverterParameter={Binding CustId}}">  to ConverterParameter={Binding InvHeader.CustId}}">
// just changes the PATH in parameter to PATH InvHeader.CustId
// we are always passing null??
// value shows as 39 InvItems
// trying a few variations, all of them return null in parameter
// <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding InvItems, Converter={StaticResource InvItemsForCustIdConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding InvHeader.CustId}}">
// <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding InvItems, Converter={StaticResource InvItemsForCustIdConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding CustId}}">
// <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding InvItems, Converter={StaticResource InvItemsForCustIdConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding CustId, Source={x:Reference parentView}, Path=InvHeader}}">

public class InvItemsForCustIdConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
      return value; // If I return the invItems then the display works, but does not Limit the InvItems to those matching the InvHeader StackLayout

      if (value is List<InvItem> invItems && parameter is string custId)
      {
          return invItems.Where(x => x.CustId == custId).ToList();
      }
      return null;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

And here's the nested XAML I'm trying to debug

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage x:Name="parentView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MauiClient"
             x:Class="MauiClient.Invoice"
             Title="Invoice">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:InvItemsForCustIdConverter x:Key="InvItemsForCustIdConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <!-- Header section -->
            <Label Text="Hospitals" FontSize="Title" />
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding invHeaders}" BackgroundColor="Blue">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Company}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Addr1}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Phone}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding CustId}" BackgroundColor="Red"  TextColor="White" />
                            <!-- Invoice items section -->
                            <Label Text="Tech Times" FontSize="Title" BackgroundColor="Yellow" TextColor="Black"/>
                            <StackLayout BindingContext="{Binding BindingContext, Source={x:Reference parentView}}" BackgroundColor="Green">
                                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding InvItems, Converter={StaticResource InvItemsForCustIdConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding CustId}}">
                                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="20">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding ItemId}" />
                                                <Label Text="{Binding CustId}" BackgroundColor="Red"  TextColor="White" />
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference parentView}, StringFormat='{0}'}" />
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Here's the basic ViewModel:

```
public class InvoiceViewModel  {
        public List<InvHeader> InvHeaders { get; set; }
        public List<InvItem> InvItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your UI is designed for a nested layout, but your data doesn’t appear to be structured for nesting

Comment: You need to pass a parameter (a constant) in the Binding itself.
You do not, that is why the converter receives a Null parameter. Text="{Binding Bla, Converter={StaticResource Bla}, CommandParameter="ConstantBla"}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In face, if we want to display the filtered data, we usually filer data on code behind instead of on the `xaml` which will result in a decrease in code efficiency.

Besides,depending on your UI display, you can redesign your data structure.

For example, you can create the data structure and filter the desired data as follows:

```
   public class InvHeader 
{
    public string Company { get; set; }

    public string Addr1 { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public int CustId { get; set; }

   // TempInvItems represents the raw data that came over
    public List<InvItem> TempInvItems { get; set;} = new List<InvItem>();

    //InvItems represents the filtered data by `CustId`
    public List<InvItem> InvItems { get; set; } = new List<InvItem>();


    public InvHeader(string Company, string Addr1, string Phone, int CustId, List<InvItem> TempInvItems) {

        this.Company = Company;
        this.Addr1 = Addr1;
        this.Phone = Phone;
        this.CustId = CustId;
        this.TempInvItems = TempInvItems;
        
        // we can filter data here
        this.InvItems = TempInvItems.Where(x => x.CustId == this.CustId).ToList();
    }
}
```

And I have achieved this function , you can refer to the following codes.

**InvItem.cs**

```
public class InvItem 
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public int CustId { get; set; }
}
```

**TestViewModel.cs**

```
public class TestViewModel 
{
    public List<InvHeader> InvHeaders { get; set; }
    public TestViewModel() {
        InvHeaders = new List<InvHeader>();

        List<InvItem> items = new List<InvItem>();
        items.Add(new InvItem { CustId = 001, ItemId = 111 });
        items.Add(new InvItem { CustId = 002, ItemId = 112 });
        items.Add(new InvItem { CustId = 003, ItemId = 113});
        items.Add(new InvItem { CustId = 001, ItemId = 100 });
        items.Add(new InvItem { CustId = 001, ItemId = 99 });

        InvHeader header1 = new InvHeader("Company1", "Addr1_1", "123456789",  001, items );
        InvHeader header2 = new InvHeader ( "Company2","Addr1_2", "123456789", 001, items );
        InvHeader header3 = new InvHeader ("Company3", "Addr1_3", "123456789", 001, items );

        InvHeaders.Add(header1);
        InvHeaders.Add(header2);
        InvHeaders.Add(header3);

    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiStuGroupApp.Views.HeaderPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiStuGroupApp.ViewModels"
             Title="HeaderPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:TestViewModel></local:TestViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <!-- Header section -->
        <Label Text="Hospitals" FontSize="Title" />
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding InvHeaders}" BackgroundColor="Blue">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Company}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Addr1}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Phone}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding CustId}" BackgroundColor="Red"  TextColor="White" />
                        <!-- Invoice items section -->
                        <Label Text="Tech Times" FontSize="Title" BackgroundColor="Yellow" TextColor="Black"/>
                        <StackLayout  >
                            <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding InvItems}" BackgroundColor="Green">
                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="20">
                                            <Label Text="{Binding ItemId}" />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding CustId}" BackgroundColor="Red"  TextColor="White" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: If I could just send the InvHeader.custId inside the parameter of InvItemsForCustIdConverter I'd be using code-behind?

But Your idea is very clever -  except that I pull the invItems and invHeaders using gRPC remotely with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and if I populated each InvHeader list item  List<InvItem> TempInvItems (all invItems) then I'd have a Massive amount of duplicated data as every single invoice would have all the invoice items for Every invoice as well as the InvItems List with just the items that matched?

Comment: Possibly I could just iterate thru all the InvHeaders in the List and populate the each specific InvHeaders.InvItems list using Where(x => x.CustId == this.CustId).ToList(); so it would Only contain invoice Items specific to that invoice?

I'll have to give this a go and work with it but .. Thanks!   for an idea that may very well solve my problem!!!

Comment: I just made the changes to your code I suggested and it .. Worked!!  Thank you so much!!!  I've been puling my hair out on this seemingly trivial issue!!

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. Happy coding... :)